# Why proguard don´t know automatically which files should be kept

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

Why android studio can´t infer which classes do we need so the other´s can be removed using shrink?

Why do we need to write manually which classes should be kept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProGuard is a general-purpose Java development tool. It knows nothing about classes that might be referred to from the Android manifest, layout resources, menu resources, preference XML, and so on.

More generally, ProGuard has no way of reliably determining what classes are loaded via reflection, which is how all of the above is implemented. For those classes, you need to teach ProGuard to keep them.

Answer (score 1):

Also the "update project" command from /ANDROID_SDK/tools/android will generate a proguard with common classes that should be kept.

The default is enough for most applications.
You should add Innerclasses that are used as listener of JavaScript on WebViews.
And the cases you find that you will need names (reflections or anything else)

The default proguard.cfg looks like this:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```